# Need to populate same value in all fields when we generate input value dynamically using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to populate same values in all input field which is generated dynamically with the help of ng-repeat. The problem which i'm facing now is i'm able to display values from input field to label field using ng-model, but i want the same in another input field. Please check the fiddle below.
Text change in one input field should reflect in all other input fields.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEvSL/15/)

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43]">
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName"  placeholder="Enter a name here">
<hr>
<h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every repeat has own scope . If you use model name without `.` in them then it'll pick ng-repeat scope as it's own.

Try like this

```
<div ng-app ng-init="myOne={}">
  <div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43]" >
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myOne.name" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <input type="text" ng-model="myOne.name"  placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/6fnco8an/)**</kbd>

Comment: Is it possible to use ng-model value from json that we are binding to ng-repeat??

Comment: Can you tell me how so that, we can group set of input controls.

Comment: you check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/5s1bfjco/5/ here you can get idea @vinothvs

Comment: I have seen this fiddle before. Problem is if i implement the way its been done in that fiddle then whatever solution you gave will contradict. My scenario is i have multiple tabs, in which there are few input fields which may repeat in other tabs. So when user enter values for one particular input field, then that should reflect in another input field in another tab. At the same time other input fields in first tab should not reflect. So i thought if i can bind that through json then it might help.

Comment: you need array of object and put each object with in different tab @vinothvs